# Strange difference between Out of bag error and test Error in Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, random-forest

I'm using random forest and the out of bag error for the level of one class is very different to its test error. I'm working with a cutt-of equal to c(0.2,0.8). Here's the case:

```
fmla <- as.formula(paste("ex ~ ", paste(names(muestra.fullarbol[,-c(1,2,3,9,10,11,12,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,29,31,32,33,34,35,36,47)]), collapse= "+")))
> bosque <- randomForest(fmla , data=muestra.fullarbol ,mtry=12, ntree=1000  , cutoff=c(0.2,0.8),importance=TRUE)
> bosque

Call:
 randomForest(formula = fmla, data = muestra.fullarbol, mtry = 12,      ntree = 1000, cutoff = c(0.2, 0.8), importance = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 1000
No. of variables tried at each split: 12

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 15.81%
Confusion matrix:
     No Si class.error
No 3999  1     0.00025
Si  758 42     0.94750
```

As we see, the out of bag error for the level "SI" is 0.94750. However If I use the test set to get a sense of the error, the result is very different:

```
res.arbol <- predict(bosque,test.fullarbol,type="class")
> summary(res.arbol)
  No   Si 
7761   43 
> table(res.arbol,test.fullarbol$ex)

res.arbol   No   Si
       No 6937  824
       Si    4   39
> prop.table(table(res.arbol,test.fullarbol$ex),1)

res.arbol         No         Si
       No 0.89382811 0.10617189
       Si 0.09302326 0.90697674
```

Now we see the error rate for the test set in the class "Si" is very low , it's equal to 0.093 and It doesn´t make sense to me.

I guess that the cut off is working just to predict out of the sample(muestra.fullarbol), but I'm not sure. What can be the reason of that huge difference?

Comment: It could be test shows a very similar confusion matrix, just that it transposed. Neither the print.randomForest or table confusion matrix states clearly if rows are true class or predicted class.

Answer (score 1):

You have transposed the confusion matrix. See test example.

```
library(randomForest)
#simulate data set
set.seed(123)
obs = 4000+800+200
vars = 6
noise.factor=.2
X =  data.frame(replicate(vars,rnorm(obs)))
yvalue = X[,1]^2+sin(X[,2]) + rnorm(obs) * noise.factor
y = factor(c("No","Si")[(yvalue<=quantile(yvalue, 800/4800))*1+1])
test = sample(obs,200)
rf = randomForest(X[-test,],y[-test],ntree=50,cutoff=c(.2,.8))
print(rf)

#yep this confusion table is inverted compared to print.randomForest
table(predict(rf,X[test,]),y[test])

#here row's a true class, and columns are predicted class
table(y[test],predict(rf,X[test,],))

#cutoff is inherrited from training, but can also be modified during prediction
table(y[test],predict(rf,X[test,]))
table(y[test],predict(rf,X[test,],cutoff=c(.2,.8)))
table(y[test],predict(rf,X[test,],cutoff=c(.7,.000001)))
```